# Pass values from one to another page

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-3.0, properties

How we can pass the values from a child window to the parent window in silverlight 3 by using Properties (ie Databinding).

In my work, it includes a parent window and a child window. The child window contains a text box, which returns a value after the hitting OK button it to Parent window. I already did this by using message sending and receiving events. But now i wish to change that to using properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parent Window:

```
ChildWindow myWin = new MyWindow("Test", "Test of shared ui elemnts");
myWin.Show();
myWin.Closed += new EventHandler(myWin_Closed);

void errorWin_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ErrorWindow wrr = (ErrorWindow)sender;
  string mytext = wrr.MyText; // Can access any property that was set ChildWindow
}
```